# Equivalent API to MmGetPhysicalAddress in WEC7

Tags: windows, windows-ce, network-driver

I am porting Windows 7 Network driver code to WEC7. I got stuck with the API MmGetPhysicalAddress. I didn't find equivalent API to this in WEC7. Can anyone help to proceed further..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`MmGetPhysicalAddress` is not available in Windows CE, but you probably don't need it anyway.

Somewhere in the `InitializeHandlerEx` callback, the driver should be calling [NdisMAllocateSharedMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff562782(v=vs.85).aspx) to allocate RX/TX buffers.

`NdisMAllocateSharedMemory` returns both the virtual and physical address of the allocated buffer, so you can keep the physical address around, and then there won't be any need to request it from the OS.

Normally the physical address would be kept in a driver-specific, per-buffer structure along with the virtual buffer address.

You can find a sample implementation of this in `C:\WINCE700\public\COMMON\oak\drivers\netcard\e100bex\60`. In `mp_init.c`, notice how `NICAllocAdapterMemory` calls `NdisMAllocateSharedMemory` and stores the physical address of each buffer in `pMpTxbuf->BufferPa`.

Comment: My requirement is to send some command to firmware, to do this I am allocating a buffer at lower layer. I am not using the buffers(tx/rx) allocated in InitializeHandlerEx to send commands to FW. As my network adapter is PCI, I need to map the virtual address to physical address of MDL. How can I get physical address of allocated MDL?

Comment: You could probably get away with using `LockPages` as suggested by Valter, but if the buffer was allocated using a non-NDIS function you would need to ensure that it is physically contiguous, assuming you are going to do a DMA transfer

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at LockPages:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee482989.aspx
But if the buffer was not allocated using NDIS functions it may not be fully contiguous in physical memory, so you may need to check that.

Comment: I used the below code to replace the Windows 7 code:                 
 DWORD pfn, offset_addr;
if(!LockPages(data, length, &pfn, (LOCKFLAG_READ | LOCKFLAG_WRITE))){
            printk("LockPages failed for block buffer\r\n");} 
offset_addr = pfn << UserKInfo[KINX_PFN_SHIFT];   
skb->wb_mapped_paddr_lo[0] = offset_addr + ((DWORD)NET_BUFFER_DATA_OFFSET(os_buf));       I am not sure whether it is correct or not? Could you check this?

Comment: I don't understand your code, missing meaning of some vars and not well formatted.
Do you get an error calling LockPages?